# What to do when the Dalvik cache is full but the operating system does not recognize it?

Tags: internal-storage, app2sd, cache, dalvik

I have a strange scenario - my `dalvik` cache is full of `dex` files - around 150MB of space, but it appears that the operating system does not recognize these files as related to any application.

I installed an `App Cleaner` and it says my cache is empty.
I went over some applications I use and saw that according to the OS they have no cache, but when I `ls` the `/sd-ext/dalvik-cache` directory I see these applications have `dex` files.

Can I simply run `rm /sd-ext/dalivk-cache/*` to solve this? Is there any risk?

Tech details:
ROM: **MIUI**
SD Extension: **A2SD+**
Rooted: **YES**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse the App-Cache with the Dalvik Cache: *App Cleaner* refers to the App-Cache (e.g. cached files from the internet, aka "webcache", or from other components of the app), while the Dalvik Cache's `.dex` files are placed on app installation (they are an optimized version of the app code). So basically you compare apples with oranges.

As for your problem: e.g. [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) offers to cleanup the Dalvik Cache. There might be other apps available providing this feature (e.g. [SystemCleanup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SystemCleanup.Inteks.org)), but in all cases this requires root -- unless you want to do a factory reset, which completely cleans the Dalvik Cache, amongst others.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I tried using Titanium Backup and it also said my dalvik cache is empty - is there any risk in deleting everything there manually?

Comment: If you have CWM Recovery installed you can clear the Dalvik cache from there. That said, there shouldn't be an issue removing them manually, but you'll likely need to be root.

Comment: Dalvik Cache empty? That's strange for a running system. And no: You can safely purge/wipe it (e.g. from ClockworkMod Recovery). Only consequence is the next boot taking longer, as it automatically re-creates all the required `.dex` files. This also happens after a factory reset (for the pre-installed apps), by the way.

Comment: Thank you all for the clarifications - I now understand the difference between dalvik and application cache and even better - now I understand my problem was not with the size of the cache but with how much data my applications keep (the whole reason for this question was due to lack of space on my phone's internal memory)

Comment: I thought so :) For all of those cases (app cache, app temp data *and* Dalvik cache), the *SystemCleanup* app seems to be helpful. Did not use it myself, but description and rating look promising. So hopefully you solved your problem -- and I'm glad I was able to enlighten and help you :)

Answer (score -1):

root phone
delete all files in folder dalvik-cache
reboot phone to  regenerate cache
this deletes useles cache